# Bokeh: App Not Visualizing--Requirements? (extra_generated_classes, jsmodel)

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, bokeh

I'm new to Bokeh, and am trying to create a web-app.  I'm having issues where when I run the server, and navigate to the specified web URL, nothing shows beyond a small "link to this" in the upper left hand corner.  For reference, I'm using python 2.7, via Anaconda, on Windows7.

I first created a simple example, modeled off of the stock applet.  I noticed that in the class Dashboard(VBox), there were, in addition, declarations of extra_generated_classes, and jsmodel.  When I omitted these two lines, nothing would show.

I read through some of the bokeh code, but I'm still not quite understanding what the two lines do, and how to set them properly.  In my new example, my formatting looks like this

```
self.children = [self.filterrow, self.lineplot1]
self.filterrow.children = [self.filter_box, self.input_box]
self.filter_box.children = [self.ticker_select, self.date_select]
self.input_box.children = [self.value_select, self.value1_select]
```

where

```
lineplot1 = Instance(Plot)
filterrow = Instance(HBox)
ticker_select = Instance(Select)
date_select = Instance(Select)
value = String(default = '')
value1 = String(default = '')
```

and in my `def create(cls)`

```
obj = cls()
obj.filterrow = HBox()
obj.filter_box = VBoxForm()
obj.input_box = VBoxForm()
```

I've compared my working applet side by side with my non-showing applet, and can't find any significant format differences.  Learning by replications, I have

```
class Dashboard(VBox):
    extra_generated_classes = [["Dashboard", "Dashboard", "VBox"]]
    jsmodel = "VBox"
```

in the non-functioning code.  Is this correct?  How should these two lines be set?  Do I need both?  Am I missing something? After repeated examination and comparison of the code, I still don't understand why one visualizes properly and the other doesn't.

If this isn't the issue, what is the best way for me to debug the visualization portion of the applet? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Issue resolved.  It turns out these values were not the issue.  However, I still don't understand the exact purpose of these two lines, and how to properly configure them (except by following the examples).  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The overall architecture of Bokeh is such that object graphs are created on the python side, and then these object graphs are recreated in the browser to actually do the rendering, etc. For all the built in objects, there is lots of plumbing to make all this happen seamlessly and transparently.  For "user created" things like apps, Bokeh (currently) needs a little help to know exactly which objects to create in the client. We are still experimenting on making this simpler and easier for users to do, so hopefully they will not be needed at all in the near future.

Comment: I see.  Thanks!  As a note, additional documentation would be great in general, but the focus on good examples is really nice.

Comment: @AmyD, you said this was not the issue. What was the issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Hey @ontologist, I ran into this problem quite a bit, but I'm sad to say that I don't have a good answer for you.  Generally, it was because I had a bug somewhere, but I also ran into this issue with specific data-related changes.  My advice is to take a fine-toothed comb to you code, to make sure that your logic is up to par (it's usually in the small details).  bigreddot, better debugging messages, beyond just a blank screen, would help a lot--is this on the development list?  Good look!